# SSIS Input variable names ending with "Specified" - why?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to consume some WCF services from SSIS. I had it working fine from a development machine. However, when another developer tries to do this, they have issues.

If the other developer copies my `.DTSX` file, then it works. However, if they create it themself, then it fails to connect (monitoring it from the WCF side).

We have noticed a BIG difference in how SSIS acts on the two machines and I suspect that is the cause of the problem. Both SSIS machines download the same WSDL data from the service. However, the Web Service Task on my machine (the functional one) has a different set of inputs than on the other dev's machine (the non-functional one). For example, if my method I was trying to call was `DoStuff(int data1, decimal data2, string msg)`, I would have 5 inputs: `data1 (int)`, `data1Specified (bool)`, `data2 (decimal)`, `data2Specified (bool)`,and `msg (string)` whereas the other machine lacked the `data1Specified` and `data2Specified` inputs. When working with other inputs, it appears that this `xxxSpecified` variable is always created by my machine for all data types except for strings (not exhaustively tested but have thrown ~8 data types in there) but the other dev's machine NEVER creates these `xxxSpecified` variables.

One more thing of note: If the other dev imports the `.DTSX` from my machine and directly runs it, it works. If he clicks on the "Download WSDL" button, even though it downloads the exact same WSDL, he gets a different set of inputs after specifying the service/method to call. So apparently his SSIS development environment is making different decisions than mine is, and we can't figure out why or how to make his act more like mine. Nor do we even realize why these `xxxSpecified` variables are apparently necessary ("Specified" exists NOWHERE in the WSDL).

**WHY does SSIS generate these `xxxSpecified` inputs, and why in one environment but not another?**

- Clarification: "GoodDevBox" creates the project manually, from scratch, and it works (i.e. has the xxxSpecified inputs). "BadDevBox" creates the project manually, from scratch, and it doesn't work (i.e. is missing the xxxSpecified inputs). The problem has nothing to do with sharing projects/solutions. In fact, sharing them is the only way to get this to work, if the "BadDevBox" doesn't reprocess the WSDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ultimately just uninstalled and reinstalled SQL Server on the problematic machines, ran Windows Updates, and the problem went away. Still have no idea what the problem was, nor do I still know the true answer to my question: WHY the variables with "Specified" at the end of the names are generated.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced that if you have config files, or if you have built/compile the solution it stores credentials and settings in the config file, including network credentials.

When passing solutions from one machine to another it keeps those credentials in the config, regardless if the user opens up the solution using their login.

Check the config file and compare them between the one that works and the one that doesn't

Comment: Based on what @internet engineer is saying, try flipping the PackageProtectionLevel from EncryptSensistiveWithUserKey to DontSaveSensitive http://bi-polar23.blogspot.com/2009/04/ssis-and-package-protectionlevel.html

Comment: I think you misunderstand (or I was confusing). The machine that doesn't work not only doesn't work with the same project (when it reprocesses the WSDL) but also when manually recreating the project from scratch. In fact, the only way to get the machine to work is by sharing files WITHOUT having the "bad" machine regenerate anything. Since it's impossible to get the "bad" machine to build this from scratch, it has nothing to do with sharing projects/solutions or anything.

Comment: We need to see the error message. Here is how you can get them:

1. http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/06/11/SSIS_3A00_-Custom-Logging-Using-Event-Handlers.aspx

2. http://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/%E2%80%9Conerror%E2%80%9D-versus-%E2%80%9Contaskfailed%E2%80%9D-event-handler-in-ssis/

Comment: I'll work on that but there ARE no errors at WSDL processing time. My question is, WHY are the two different SSIS dev boxes generating a different set of inputs for this web service? Is this not known to anybody? The same WSDL results in two very different sets of Input parameters.

Comment: it's hard to determine that from the info provided. Can you attach a log file to see the differences?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what "log file" you want. I want to know why SSIS generates the inputs in this way. This generation process creates no log file. What you gave me links to log execution errors. My question is not about execution, my question is about why SSIS generates this code at development-time.